# How to run multiple queries as array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got a PHP script that I need to run several queries of the same thing just different parameters, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Weather_records 
WHERE type = 1, 

SELECT * 
FROM Weather_records 
WHERE type = 2
```

Is there a way to run this as one query and just put it in a array or something?

Comment: there are several ways, depending on what you want to achieve. From views, a loop, a `where type IN`, ... too many options and possibilities here!

Comment: its for view, I know I could just use a loop but I'm doing like 12 quarries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the problem wrong and ended up using one query to get the whole table and then used a loop and a switch case.

Answer (score 6):

Use IN

```
SELECT * FROM Weather_records WHERE type IN (1,2)
```

Comment: For ranges you can do `WHERE type BETWEEN 1 AND 2`.

Comment: Well I will need to do something with each record. So how do I take this query and get each record from it separately?